# Spring boot Deployment in Websphere

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, spring-data-jpa, websphere

We are trying to deploy a Java 8 Spring boot application using Spring data Jpa into an IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.21 server. The application runs fine in Local, but we cannot get it running in WebSphere.

This is what im getting an error while deploy.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2/3/23 13:29:39:601 IST] 00000146 SystemOut     O 2023-03-02 13:29:39.600 ERROR 867310 --- [ebContainer : 0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1464) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:642) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1042) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5568) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5694) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83) [na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287) [na:1.8.0]
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [na:1.8.0]
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257) [na:1.8.0]
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096) [na:1.8.0]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831) [na:1.8.0]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813) [na:1.8.0]
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1351) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) [bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1244) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246) [wsccore-core_module.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:641) [appmanagement-appmanagement_module.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source) [struts.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:982) [isclite.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:529) [isclite.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:350) [isclite.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:952) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean.<clinit>(ServletListenerRegistrationBean.java:68) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:262) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext$$Lambda$925/0x00000000fb367d10.onStartup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:193) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:254) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:945) ~[na:2.9 (10-22-2021)]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:890) ~[na:2.9 (10-22-2021)]
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:144) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873) ~[na:2.9 (10-22-2021)]
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:598) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873) ~[na:2.9 (10-22-2021)]
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:630) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf212202.02]]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873) ~[na:2.9 (10-22-2021)]
```

My pom file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kgisl.bsibschedulers</groupId>
    <artifactId>BSIB-Schedulers</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>bsibschedulers</name>
    <description>BSIB Scheduler services</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Schedulers</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In Main Class

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class BsibschedulersApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("BsibschedulersApplication Started");
        SpringApplication.run(BsibschedulersApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println("BsibschedulersApplication Configure");
        return application.sources(BsibschedulersApplication.class);
    }

}
```

I'm exporting as war file.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that the servlet API version is different between Spring boot 2.7 and websphere 8.5.

Comment: For Spring boot 2.7.7 which version of websphere is suitable to deploy? or else what did I change?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7.7 has dependencies on Java EE 8 technologies it would appear.  WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 supports Java EE 6 technologies.  Version 9.0.5 supports Java EE 7 technologies.  Open and WebSphere Liberty support Java EE 6 Web Profile, 7, 8, and Jakarta 8 and 9. So it would appear that WebSphere Liberty (which come with WebSphere Application Server) is the environment where you should deploy a Spring Boot 2.7.7 application.

Comment: @JaredAnderson - Spring Boot 2.7.7 with Jakarta 8, for this which version of websphere is  suitable to deploy.

Comment: WebSphere Liberty would be the WebSphere Application Server offering that supports Jakarta EE 8.  Traditional WebSphere Application Server's latest release is 9.0.5.x and it supports Java EE 7.  There is not a version that supports Java / Jakarta EE 8 or 9.  WebSphere Liberty is where Java / Jakarta EE 8 support is provided.  As stated in my previous comment, WebSphere Liberty is part of WebSphere Application Server and comes with it.  WebSphere Liberty has supported Java / Jakarta EE 8 technologies since 18.0.0.2.

Comment: Same question accidentally posted twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75615930/deployment-in-websphereibm-for-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.7.7 has dependencies on Java EE 8 technologies. WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 supports Java EE 6 technologies. Version 9.0.5 supports Java EE 7 technologies. Open and WebSphere Liberty support Java EE 6 Web Profile, 7, 8, and Jakarta 8 and 9. So WebSphere Liberty (which come with WebSphere Application Server) is the environment where you should deploy a Spring Boot 2.7.7 application.

Comment: Then how should I deploy this combination in websphere. Any other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Use WebSphere Liberty or use a version of Spring Boot that uses Java EE 6 APIs with traditional WebSphere Application Server version 8.5.5.x or a version of Spring Boot that uses Java EE 7 APIs with version 9.0.5.x are the options I see here.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.7.9 or 2.7.7 requires at least Servlet 5.0 specification and Java 17. It is not compatible with WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.21, which supports Servlet 3.0 and Java 7/8.

To deploy a Spring Boot application on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.21, you need to use an earlier version of Spring Boot that is compatible with Servlet 3.0 and Java 7/8. For example, you could use Spring Boot 2.3.x or 2.4.x.

It's important to note that even if a version of Spring Boot is compatible with a particular version of WebSphere Liberty, there may still be other compatibility issues with other libraries or dependencies used in your application. It's always a good idea to thoroughly test your application before deploying it to a production environment.

Make Sure Javax-servlet-api dependency look like this

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>{Compatible Version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

In this Im not using Scope provided, because if you have marked it with a "provided" scope, which means that it will be provided by the server and not included in the WAR file when the application is packaged.

you can remove the "provided" scope from the javax.servlet-api dependency in your pom.xml file. This will ensure that the dependency is included in the WAR file when the application is packaged and deployed to the server.

Spring Boot 2.6.x is compatible with Java 8 and requires at least Servlet 4.0 specification, which is supported by WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.21.

Therefore, you can use Spring Boot 2.6.3 with Java 8 and deploy your application to WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.21.

Note: This is for **WebSphere Liberty - 8.5.5.21** not for WebSphere traditional.

Hope This will Help for some one.

Comment: Sorry the Above Answer is not Working

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                        https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <liberty.version>8.5.5.21</liberty.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oracle-maven-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Schedulers</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liberty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverName>defaultServer</serverName>
                    <packageName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</packageName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

For WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.21 supports only 1.x series of Spring boot.

The Above pom is Working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your pom file :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```